# How do I upgrade from Mac 10.5.8 to 10.6.4

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade, osx-leopard

I would like to upgrade my iMac which is running now 10.5.8 to 10.6.4

Can somebody point me to some articles discussing about Mac upgrades?

Comment: Do you have a Snow Leopard disc?

Answer (score 3):

Lifehacker has a good [step-by-step guide](http://lifehacker.com/5348150/how-to-upgrade-from-leopard-to-snow-leopard) on upgrading from Leopard to Snow Leopard.

You will need to purchase the Snow Leopard upgrade DVD from somewhere that sells Apple software. Usually it is around $29 US.